# How to sort an array in iOS?

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

i am newbie in iOS Development. My array Contain Dictionary Value Key like as

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in self.imageArray )
    {
    [self.imagesa addObject:@{@"demopage":[dict valueForKey:@"demopage"]}];
    }
```

Here my "demoPage" Key Value Contain Two Key like as "link" and "Pageno" here link contain my ImageURL and "pageno" contain page number like as

```
-demopage
{
link:"URL",
 page_no: "12"
},
{
link:"URL",
page_no: "13"
},
{
link: "URL",
page_no: "14"
},
{
link: "",
page_no: "3"
},
{
 link:"URL",
 page_no: "31"
},
{
link: "URL",
page_no: "32"
},
```

When i parsed it then i get data in This range like as 12,13,14,3,31,32 i want to arrange this image like as page number based i want it like as 1,2,3 up to data array.

Comment: Have you try something?

Comment: let me clarify this: you want to sort the _12, 13, 14, 3, 31, 32_ as _3, 12, 13, 14, 31, 32_? because you don't have _1_, _2_ in your model...

Comment: @holex my Data is solong then i not write it but i want to sort like as from 1 to my data array count.

Comment: @Ramesh, so... where have you been stuck actually?

Comment: did u even bother searching for a solution?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Yup bro but it is not working i try for it like as 
     self.imagesa = [[imgsLinkArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
     {
                         if ([obj1[@"page_no"] intValue] > [obj2[@"page_no"] intValue])
    {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
     }
     else if ([obj1[@"page_no"] intValue] < [obj2[@"page_no"] intValue])
     {
     return NSOrderedAscending;
     }
     return NSOrderedSame;
     }] mutableCopy];
But it is Not Working.

Comment: @Ramesh did you see my answer?

Comment: @vikingosegundo sorry

Comment: @vikingosegundo - yes you are ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason you are storing the page number as a string and not a number. So a simple sort will sort it alphabetically.

i.e. 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 20, 21, 235, 3, 35, 4

You need it to sort alphanumerically which you can do like this...

```
NSSortDescriptor *alphaNumSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"page_no" ascending:YES comparator:^(NSString *string1, NSString *string2) {
    return [string1 compare:string2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];

NSArray *sortedArray = [self.theArrayYouWantToSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[alphaNumSD]];
```

---

#### Example

```
NSArray *originalArray = @[
                           @{@"page_no": @"27"},
                           @{@"page_no": @"1"},
                           @{@"page_no": @"12"},
                           @{@"page_no": @"23"},
                           @{@"page_no": @"3"},
                           @{@"page_no": @"2"},
                           @{@"page_no": @"17"},
                           ];

NSSortDescriptor *alphaNumSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"page_no"
                                                             ascending:YES
                                                            comparator:^(NSString *string1, NSString *string2)
{
    return [string1 compare:string2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];


NSArray *sortedArray = [originalArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[alphaNumSD]];
NSLog(@"%@", sortedArray);
```

#### Output

```
(
        {
        "page_no" = 1;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 2;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 3;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 12;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 17;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 23;
    },
        {
        "page_no" = 27;
    }
)
```

It definitely works as expected.

Comment: @Ramesh DON'T SHOUT! The array you want to sort. In your case it is probably `self.imagesa` but it's hard to tell from your question. I took it from the other answer. Surely that is obvious by the fact that it is called array and I am sorting it?

Comment: i am not shout first of all NSSortDescriptor *alphaNumSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"page_no" ascending:YES comparator:^(NSString *string1, NSString *string2) {
                return [string1 compare:string2 options:NSNumericSearch];
            }];
            
        NSArray *sortedArray = [self.imagesa sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[alphaNumSD]];
        self.imagesa=[sortedArray mutableCopy]; But it is not working.

Comment: @Ramesh THIS IS SHOUTING!!!!!!!!! What do you mean when you say it is not working? That description of what is happening is useless.

Comment: @Ramesh well, you have the code here to do exactly what you want. You obviously need to sort the correct array in the first place but there is no real way to tell which array that is. You don't really explain anything in your question. You haven't said what exactly hasn't worked other than saying "it doesn't work". So I can't help beyond here. But you have all the code to do exactly what you need so an upvote and accept would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: @Fogmeister, hope u don't mind that I added an example that proves your code correct.

Comment: @vikingosegundo not at all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *ordersArray = info[@"result"];

NSArray *properSortedArray = [ordersArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                              ^(id obj1, id obj2)
                              {
                                  NSInteger value1 = [[obj1 objectForKey: @"orderId"] intValue];
                                  NSInteger value2 = [[obj2 objectForKey: @"orderId"] intValue];
                                  if (value1 > value2)
                                  {
                                      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                                  }
                                  if (value1 < value2)
                                  {
                                      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                                  }
                                  return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
                              }];
```

Comment: This is effectively the same as my code but with more code. You seem to be reimplementing the AlphaNumeric compare for strings. Why not just use the AlphaNumeric compare for strings instead?

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
[self.dataArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"page_no" ascending:YES]]]
```

Comment: @Ramesh it's because `page_no` is **bizarrely** stored as a string not a number. You need to do an alphanumeric sort.

Comment: @Fogmeister here my page_no key value only number value like as 1,2,3,4,5 and i want based on my Pageno respected image in Ascending order.

Comment: @Ramesh did you assing the result of method do self.imagesa?

Comment: `sortedArray…` does return the sorted array, but you aren't assigning them to any variable.